# how many 4-digit positive integers are there in which each digit after the leftmost digit is smaller than the digit to its left?

Tags: combinatorics

how many 4-digit positive integers are there, in which each digit after the leftmost digit, is smaller than the digit to its left ?

I have tried doing this problem by coming up with the combinations of all 4 digit integers, and then removing the ones that doesn't meet the combination, and than multiplying - but cannot get the answer which is 210 integers.

Answer (score 3):

Choose four distinct digits from $10$ and then put them in decreasing order.

Answer (score 0):

I make it to be 210, I hard calculated the terms up to 6000 terms. then constructed a formula, for 3ABC (where ABC are digits) there is 1 term, for 4ABC you get 4 combinations, for 5ABC you get 10 combinations and for 6ABC you get 20 combinations. now the difference between these terms is 3,6,10. these are triangle numbers so extending this the next term for 7ABC is 35, 8ABC is 56 and 9ABC is 84, (difference being 15,21,28. next 3 triangle numbers) summing these values gives 210 by my calculations. Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry for the incorrect post a second ago, i made a silly typo in my workings.